# Dynamic SQL shows successful but does not update rows

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamicquery

I am new to SQL Server and stored procedures, with that being said I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 trying to make a dynamic query that allows me to pass in the table name and a few parameters to update some rows.

The stored procedure runs and says completed successfully but the rows never get updated. If I break up the queries and run them individually they work but all together nothing.

I tried using print and select statements to show my queries and progress but nothing prints out.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_testing_drew]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Table_Name sysname,
    @id int,
    @username varchar(25)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @recipeName varchar(25),
        @idApp varchar(10),
        @DynamicSQL1 nvarchar(4000),
        @DynamicSQL2 nvarchar(4000),
        @DynamicSQL3 nvarchar(4000),
        @DynamicSQL4 nvarchar(4000)

    -- Set the recipe name, finding it first by its ID  
    --SELECT @recipeName = Recipe_Name FROM LC2Recipes WHERE LC2RecipesID = 551;
    SET @DynamicSQL1 = N'SELECT '+@recipeName+' = Recipe_Name FROM '+@Table_Name+' WHERE LC2RecipesID = '+CAST(@id AS varchar(10))+';'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL1

    -- Get the ID of the approved recipe
    --SET @DynamicSQL2 = N'SELECT TOP 1 ' + @idApp + ' = ' + @Table_Name + 'ID FROM ' + @Table_Name + ' WHERE Recipe_Name = ''' + @recipeName + ''' ORDER BY Major_Revision DESC;'
    SET @DynamicSQL2 = N'SELECT TOP 1 '+@idApp+' = LC2RecipesID FROM '+@Table_Name+' WHERE Recipe_Name = '''+@recipeName+''' ORDER BY Major_Revision DESC;'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL2

    -- 4 is Archived, 1 is approved, set the user who approved
    --SET @DynamicSQL3 = N'UPDATE ' + @Table_Name + ' SET Status = 4 WHERE Recipe_Name = ''' + @recipeName + '';
    SET @DynamicSQL3 = N'UPDATE '+@Table_Name+' SET Status = 4 WHERE Recipe_Name = '''+@recipeName+''';'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL3

    --SET @DynamicSQL4 = N'UPDATE ' + @Table_Name + ' SET Approved_By = ''' + @username + ''', Status = 1 WHERE ' + @Table_Name + 'ID = ' + CAST(@idApp AS varchar(10));
    SET @DynamicSQL4 = N'UPDATE '+@Table_Name+' SET Approved_By = '''+@username+''', Status = 1 WHERE '+@Table_Name+'ID = '+@idApp+';'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL4
END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Another side note: as coded this is vulnerable to sql injection. When doing this type of procedure you should wrap your object names in QUOTENAME. It isn't perfect but is a minimal step in preventing injection attack.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks, Ill keep that in mind going forward, right now im just working locally, not on a web app.

Comment: only the updates are failing?

Comment: @Drewdin: doesn't matter what kind of app - just **don't use** `sp_` as your stored procedure prefix - **not ever** ....

Comment: The reason you are having problems here is because each execution of dynamic sql runs in its own scope. As such, your variables are not in scope. Change your code to select each dynamic sql and you will see that some of them are NULL because your recipe and idApp variables will be NULL.

Comment: @smog to be honest, i cant tell in the stored procedure, everything I tried to print out does not get printed. But yes, the selected rows do not get updated

Comment: I would rewrite this entire thing to be a single dynamic query with multiple statements.

Comment: @ Sean Lange, so do a SELECT from @DynamicSQL4 for instance?

Comment: Just change your very first exec statement to "select @DynamicSql1". It will be NULL because recipe is NULL and adding a NULL will result in NULL.

Comment: yup, got null, How do I keep everything in scope? Just concatenate one large query string? Thanks

Comment: Yes one big nasty string. BTW, from the code you posted you updating the same table twice with different values and different criteria? This seems a bit strange but maybe that is correct.

Comment: unfortunately the updating twice is a stop gap until we can modify the table during a shutdown.

Comment: I concatenated one long string and got the same result, also got null with a select of the dynamic query. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the values of variable `@recipeName`  & `@idApp`. This is causing the problem , just set the values of these variable and you should be fine,

Comment: I am setting the variables in the queries, select @recipeName = Recipe_name, etc... Should I be doing it a different way?